# Undefined variables

Tags: variables, xdebug, php

I have defined the 2 variables, in contact and shirts. As you can see they are also in the li in header. Still i get the message that both of the variables are undefined.

I get this error message:

> ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for ( ! )
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: section in
>   C:\wamp\www\Test\shirts4mike\inc\header.php on line 17
>
> Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0003243592{main}(
>   )..\index.php:0
>
> 20.0006246920 include( 'C:\wamp\www\Test\shirts4mike\inc\header.php' )..\index.php:3 ">

and the same for line 18.

**shirts.php**:

```
     <?php
            $pageTitle = "Mike's Full Catalog of Shirts";
            $section = "shirts";
            include('inc/header.php'); ?>

                    <div class="section page">
                            <h1>Mikes&rsquo;s Full Catalog of Shirts</h1>
                    </div>

            <?php include ('inc/footer.php'); ?>
```

**contact.php**:

```
<?php
    $pageTitle = "Contact Mike";
     $section = "contact";
     include('inc/header.php'); ?>

           <div class="section page">

           <h1>Contact</h1>

           </div>


<?php include ('inc/footer.php'); ?>
```

**header.php**:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title> <?php echo $pageTitle ?></title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700" type="text/css">
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        </head>
        <body>

                <div class="header">

                        <div class="wrapper">

                                <h1 class="branding-title"><a href="./">Shirts 4 Mike</a></h1>

                                <ul class="nav">
                                        <li class="shirts <?php if ($section == "shirts"){ echo "on"; } ?>"><a href="shirts.php">Shirts</a></li>
                                        <li class="contact <?php if ($section == "contact"){ echo "on"; } ?>"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                                        <li class="cart"><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                                </ul>

                        </div>

                </div>

                <div id="content">
```

Comment: please include code IN your question. Especially since you've apparently linked to a private paste...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide an example that's *as small as possible* while still demonstrating your problem. Further, it usually helps to include the *exact* error message.

Comment: As @AD7six said... please, include the code in your question.

Comment: What variable is undefined?  In what file?  P.S. We can't view your `shirts.php`, it's private.  Please put the code in the question, not on pastebin.

Comment: Just guessing: !@ !== @!   though you shouldn't generally suppress errors using @.... it's better to fix errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see `SCREAM` in a PHP error message like this, it is due to the following circumstances:

1. You have PHP's xDebug extension installed.
2. xDebug is configured to prevent error supression.
3. Your PHP code is attempting to suppress an error message using the `@` symbol or other error suppression mechanisms, and xDebug is overriding this.

xDebug is a PHP extension designed to help with debugging PHP programs. It should generally not be installed on a production system; only on a development system.

xDebug has a setting called "Scream" which is designed to prevent errors being suppressed. This is again intended for use in a development system. The developer may want errors to be supressed under normal circumstances, but while debugging it is useful to see those errors. So the scream setting overrides all of PHP's normal ways of hiding error messages. This is useful for debugging, but is a terrible thing to have on a production system.

xDebug should never be installed on a public facing production server, so if that describes your system you should remove it, or ask for it to be removed. This could be as simple as modifying the PHP.ini file to remove the references to xDebug (although that will just disable the extension rather than un-installing it).

If it is installed and you can't do anything about it, then you need to find a better web host that doesn't install development tools on production systems.

Having said all of that, if you're getting the message that `$section is undefined`, then it does imply a bug in the code that needs to be fixed.

The error is occurring in `header.php`, when it is included from `index.php`.

You've shown us `shirts.php` and `contact.php`, both of which set `$section` correctly. You *haven't* shown us `index.php`, but I would guess that it includes `header.php` in the same way as the others, but doesn't set `$section` like the others do.

You can therefore fix the bug by editing `index.php` so that it sets `$section` in the same way a the other pages do. Even if it just sets it to a blank string, that will be enough to fix the bug.

I hope that helps.

Comment: good point about xdebug also implementing this but I don't think xdebug has that error header. I doubt any web host uses wamp though (read the path in the error message) :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now. I added $section to my index, and it solved the problem. 

As you can tell im pretty new at this, i solved the problem but will look in to xdbug and your other points. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

### You're looking at the wrong files

The stack trace indicates that two files were included to get to this particular error (in reverse order):

- `inc\header.php`
- `index.php`

In the question, `index.php` isn't shown - but it is most likely that you have:

```
<?php
$pageTitle = "something";
include('inc/header.php');
```

i.e. the variables that are missing are *not* declared before they are used in the code that you are executing.

### SCREAM

[scream](http://php.net/manual/en/book.scream.php) is an extension which makes it ignore use of the `@` operator - i.e. somewhere in the code that is being executed, it is being used,  it's generally held as bad practice to ignore errors. You can however [turn scream off](http://php.net/manual/en/scream.configuration.php) - which is appropriate for a production/live app, though of course the errors/warnings/notices should be addressed.

Comment: +1 I actually didn't realise Scream was its own separate extension as well; I've only ever seen it as part of xDebug.